# Overrule CSS alignment for right-to-left written languages, based on conditionally set variable

Tags: php, css

Each of my pages has http headers in which the language code (two chars) is given by some magical variable that some how returns the current set language `$_SESSION['language'`

```
header('Content-language: ' . $_SESSION['language']);
// outputs HTTP Headers  "en" or "ar" (ar = arabic spoken in Dubai etc) etcettera
```

Now, I would like to set the alignment of my p selector to right, as opposed to left, via css property `text-alignment: right` whenever either HTTP headers say language is `ar` or `fa`

How could I make an if statement in my (thankfully already php-ised all.css file?
sothat I can append this into the top or bottom of the rest of the css files included into the all.css? I hav a feeling it should look something like this (please don't laugh!) Thanks very much for your suggestions!

```
/*
| overrule the alignment of html/body/p text when $_SESSION['language' = ar/fa  
*/

if $_SESSION['language'] <<==>> "ar" OR "fa"
   then add rule to css:  "text-alignment: right !important"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['language']) && ($_SESSION['language'] == 'ar' || $_SESSION['language'] == 'fa')) {
    echo "text-alignment: right !important"
}
```

Comment: +1 @James works beautifully!  the second line had to be `echo "p{text-align:right !important}";`  my mistake! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If your CSS file is actually a PHP file that sends out CSS headers then you can access the session value from inside your CSS file.  Alternatively you can pass the data as a url parameter when you link in your stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.php?lang=<?php echo $_SESSION['language']; ?>" type=...
```

Comment: +1 thanks @ShaneTheHat however I could not figure this one out myself, (my lack of expertise)